# LLenando Picker Xamarin Forms con Json

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Hola estoy tratando de llenar un `picker` en xamarin con un Json, y necesito cambiar los valores de `SelectedIndex` default por `CLAVE_E` del **json**

este es mi código

```
    public partial class detail : ContentPage
{
public detail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
        getEstados();                
    }        
private async void  getEstados() {
if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
{
    var uri = "http://miapi/ruta/Estados";
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);
    var client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

    switch (response.StatusCode)
    {
        case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------_____:Here status 500");


            break;
        case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK:
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------_____:Here status 200");

            try
            {
                HttpContent content = response.Content;
                string xjson = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();



                var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Estados>(xjson);

                PickerEstados.TextColor = Color.FromHex("#4E8F75");
                PickerEstados.TitleColor = Color.FromHex("#4E8F75");
                foreach (var item in json.Table)
                {
                    PickerEstados.Items.Add(item.ESTADO.ToString() + "_" +item.CLAVE_E);
                    PickerEstados.SelectedIndex = item.CLAVE_E;
                }
                PickerEstados.SelectedIndexChanged += PickerEstados_SelectedIndexChanged;


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("", "" + ex.ToString(), "ok");
                var x = ex.ToString();

                return;
            }
            break;
        case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound:

            await DisplayAlert("error 404", "servidor no encontrado ", "ok");
            break;
    }
}

}
private void PickerEstados_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


 var x = PickerEstados.Items[PickerEstados.SelectedIndex];
 var x1 = PickerEstados.SelectedIndex;


DisplayAlert("", "_" +  x+ " _ " + x1 , "ok");
}
}
```

La cuestión es que `SelectedIndex` del primer objeto me da `0` en lugar de la **CLAVE_E** que pretendo que reciba
este mi picker

```
`       <Picker x:Name="PickerEstados" 
                Title="Select Location" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Table}"
                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ESTADO}"
                SelectedIndex="{Binding CLAVE_E}"
                VerticalOptions="Center"   />`
```

y este es mi modelo y mi json

```
public class Table
{
    public int CLAVE_E { get; set; }
    public string ESTADO { get; set; }

    public int CLAVE_S { get; set; }
    public int CLAVE_M { get; set; }
    public int CLAVE_C { get; set; }
    public int CLAVE_P { get; set; }
     public string CP { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCTO { get; set; }
    public string MUNICIPIO { get; set; }
    public string SUUCRSAL { get; set; }

}

public class Estados
{
    public List<Table> Table { get; set; }
}
```

json

```
{
    "Table": [
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 1,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "AGUASCALIENTES",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 2,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "BAJA CALIFORNIA",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 3,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "BAJA CALIFORNIA SUR",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 4,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "CAMPECHE",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 5,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "COAHUILA DE ZARAGOZA",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 6,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "COLIMA",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 7,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "CHIAPAS",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 8,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "CHIHUAHUA",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 9,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "DISTRITO FEDERAL",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 10,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "DURANGO",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 11,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "GUANAJUATO",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 12,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "GUERRERO",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 13,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "HIDALGO",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 14,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "JALISCO",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 15,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "MEXICO",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 16,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "MICHOACAN DE OCAMPO",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 17,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "MORELOS",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 18,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "NAYARIT",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 19,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "NUEVO LEON",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 20,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "OAXACA",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 21,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "PUEBLA",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 22,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "QUERETARO",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 23,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "QUINTANA ROO",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 24,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "SAN LUIS POTOSI",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 25,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "SINALOA",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 26,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "SONORA",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 27,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "TABASCO",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 28,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "TAMAULIPAS",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 29,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "TLAXCALA",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 30,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "VERACRUZ LLAVE",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 31,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "YUCATAN",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 32,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "ZACATECAS",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        },
        {
            "CLAVE_E": 0,
            "CLAVE_S": 0,
            "CLAVE_M": 0,
            "CLAVE_C": 0,
            "CLAVE_P": 0,
            "ESTADO": "NO APLICA",
            "CP": null,
            "PRODUCTO": null,
            "MUNICIPIO": null,
            "SUUCRSAL": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Cuando pido el `PickerEstados.SelectedIndex` del primer objeto me da `0` en vez la clave que se supone le estoy asignando.
Alguien sabe que esta pasando?

Este es código del servicio que estoy consumiendo

`public System.Data.DataSet WsExecuteEstados() {
            object[] results = this.Invoke("WsExecuteEstados", new object[0]);
            return ((System.Data.DataSet)(results[0]));
        }`

Luego lo paso por aquí para convertirlo en **json**

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Estados()
    {
        WebReference.CPAWS fx = new WebReference.CPAWS();
        var fxx = fx.WsExecuteEstados();
        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer json = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
        json.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

        json.ObjectCreationHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ObjectCreationHandling.Replace;
        json.MissingMemberHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;
        json.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

        json.Converters.Add(new DataSetConverter());

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw);


        writer.QuoteChar = '"';
        json.Serialize(writer, fxx);

        string output = sw.ToString();
        writer.Close();
        sw.Close();

        var output2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Estados>(output);
        return Json(output2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Breakpoint en y muestra lo que hay en las variables: `xjson` y `json `

Comment: ok la variable `xjson` es el mismo json que esta arriba y la varibale `json` que es donde quiero hacer `DeserializeObject`me da ese error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este mainPage, haces todo, llamar al servicio, rellenar el picker, realizas el Cast del elemento seleccionado y tambien esta la clase declarada sobre el objeto a usar.

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FillPicker();
    }

    void Picker_SelectedIndexChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var i = (Table)PickerEstados.SelectedItem;
        DisplayAlert("",   i.CLAVE_E  , "ok");
    }
    private async void FillPicker()
    {

            var uri = "http://miapi/ruta/Estados";
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);
            var client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            switch (response.StatusCode)
            {
                case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------_____:Here status 500");
                    break;
                case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK:
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------_____:Here status 200");
                    try
                    {                            
                        HttpContent content = response.Content;
                         PickerEstados.TextColor = Color.FromHex("#4E8F75");
                        PickerEstados.TitleColor = Color.FromHex("#4E8F75");
                        var json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                         var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Estados>(json);
                        PickerEstados.ItemsSource = result.Table;
                        PickerEstados.SelectedIndexChanged += PickerEstados_SelectedIndexChanged;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("", "" + ex.ToString(), "ok");
                        var x = ex.ToString();
                        return;
                    }
                    break;
                case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound:

                    await DisplayAlert("error 404", "servidor no encontrado ", "ok");
                    break;
            }
}


 public class Table
        {
            public int CLAVE_E { get; set; }
            public int CLAVE_S { get; set; }
            public int CLAVE_M { get; set; }
            public int CLAVE_C { get; set; }
            public int CLAVE_P { get; set; }
            public string ESTADO { get; set; }
            public object CP { get; set; }
            public object PRODUCTO { get; set; }
            public object MUNICIPIO { get; set; }
            public object SUUCRSAL { get; set; }
        }

        public class Estados
        {
            public List<Table> Table { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: eso me da lo siguiente ` Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SUMATEAPPT2.Modelos.JWS.Estados]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
... not a collection type like an array or List<T>)`

Comment: porque estas intentado desearializar el objeto con Estados, deberias usar tu clase Table,  var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Table>>(json);

Comment: Te hago la sugerencia que intentes mantener los mismos nombres de tu objetos y tu lista, porque a tu objeto le llamas Table y haces referencia a un Estado de Mexico, y cuando haces tu List<> les pones Table en singular cuando es un listado de registros. Estoy seguro que te sera mas facil de leer cuando tengas una cantidad mayor de array o List<T> y para quien lea tu codigo.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104728/discussion-on-answer-by-ramiro-barone-llenando-picker-xamarin-forms-con-json).

Answer (score 2):

Si es lo que creo que es, debes reemplazar:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Estados>>(xjson);
```

Por esto:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Estados>(xjson);
```

Sucede que la clase:

```
public class Estados
{
    public List<Table> Table { get; set; }
}
```

Cuenta con una lista, y lo que estás haciendo es tratar de trabajar una lista de una lista, motivo por el cual el compilador te dice:

> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array

Comment: pues si, si hago si me convierte el objeto, pero necesito pararselo a el picker y haciendo eso ya no me permite pasarselo para llenar

Comment: ¿Qué te genera el autocomplete cuando le das un `item.` ?

Comment: He cambiado la respuesta, parece ser que si logré llenarlo, cuando menos no me tira nngun error si no hasta que toco el picker

Comment: ¿Has leído la documentación del picker?

Comment: si estoy usando esta referencia https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-items justo `.Items.Add` es lo que le intento pasar

Answer (score 1):

al picker le estas agregando items con

```
 PickerEstados.Items.Add(item.ESTADO.ToString());
```

pero en el xaml le estas dando

```
 {Binding Estados}
```

No sé si tienes una propiedad de Estados porque en el código que compartiste no lo veo... Deberías borrar el *binding* y solo considerar el primero... o
podrías tener una propiedad

```
public ObservableCollection<Estado> Estados
{
    get => _estado;
    set => SetProperty(ref _estado, value);
}
```

si trabajas con prism o

```
public ObservableCollection<Estado> Estados
{
    get => _estado;
    set => _estado=value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

// Esta es un metodo que devuelve una List el T puede reemplazarlo por una //clase o usarlo de esa forma si sabes como llamarlo luego. 
//Luego de que la llamada da OK, deserializa el objeto a un List

```
     HttpRequestMessage requestMessage;
     HttpClient client;
     HttpResponseMessage httpResponse;
     HttpContent content;

    public async Task<List<T>> GetAllMovement(string url)
 {
    List<T> resultado = new List<T>();
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);

    httpResponse = await GetHttpResponse(uri, HttpMethod.Get);
    if (httpResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        content = httpResponse.Content;
                        var json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        resultado = 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>json);

                    }
                    return resultado;
                }


    private async void FillPicker()
    {
       Picker.ItemsSource = await GetAllMovement();
    }
    private void picker1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Table estado = (Table)Picker.SelectedItem;
    }
```

Comment: hay una ultima cosa ... si ves intento asignar el `PickerEstados.SelectedIndex = item.CLAVE_E;` con un clave particular, pero no logra asignarla , sabes como puedo hacer eso?

Comment: No es necesario que asignes tu propiedad al index, tienes métodos y propieades para buscar y propiedades, o puede recorrer el picker tal cual un List<> y buscar el CLAVE_E. De todos modos para que querrias asignar tu id al index?

Comment: necesito hacer llamadas a partir del index o bueno en este cao a partir de `CLAVE_E` voy a cambiar un  poco el codigo para que veas lo que estoy tratando de hacer es recibir el `SelectedIndex` en otro metodo

Comment: algo como `PickerEstados_SelectedIndexChanged`?? podrías poner un ejemplo o editar tu respuesta?

Comment: Modifique la solucion y coloque un cuarto punto con el ejemplo.

Comment: ok porbé tu paso 1 y 2 ambos me dan error, por ultimo si intento tu paso 4 con lo que ya tenía me dice que no puede agregarle  `SelectedItemChangedEventArgs` que debo pasarle un **eventHandler**

Comment: Pon el codigo completo, porque esto lo hago todos los días y no puede dar error. voy a modificar mi respuesta con código real mio y debes adaptarlo al tuyo.

Comment: Listo ya cambié todo el código por lo que actualmente

Comment: Te agrego un ejemplo que funciona bien. Tenes que adaptar a tu clase y tu direccion Uri.

Comment: pregunta este `(Estado)Picker.SelectedItem` ese `Estado` de donde sale?

Comment: Modifique la respuesta con tu clase y en mi deserializacion funciona correctamente con tu json.

Comment: la `T` es de la clase Table?? o es la respuesta de arriba?

Comment: Perdon, es la de arriba, hice el comentario sobre la respuesta equivocada.

Comment: uffff creo que tras esta larga odisea ya quedo dame tantito chance voy a modificar una de tus respuestas con lo que me funcionó y te doy la respuesta